# Generating tar.gz file with PHP, file being double compressed

Tags: php, apache, gzip

I have a PHP script as part of my system which will combine files into a tar.gz, tar.xz or zip file and deliver it to the user browsing the site.

Download of tar.xz and zip files works flawlessly.
But with tar.gz, I am having not so much luck.

I'm using Apache 2.2.15 with the mod_deflate module enabled and set up to gzip output.

If you make a request with Accept-Encoding: gzip, it sends the tar.gz double-compressed ( e.g. gz(gz(tar(...))) ), which, from what I can understand, is the 'correct' way (even though it's uselessly double-compressing).

I'm setting the header `Content-Type: application/x-gzip` from within PHP while delivering this file.

When I do this, it seems as though Firefox doesn't reverse the 2nd layer of gzip compression when downloading (the layer that Apache is applying).
When I change the content type to something else, the issue does not occur, and I get the proper tar.gz file.
In both cases, Apache is adding another layer of compression and sending the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header.

How can I resolve this issue while keeping the desired Content-Type so the user can actually open the file in the correct program?

---

But I know that this is an example of the XY Problem, since the **correct** fix would be to disable Apache's extra compression.
I don't, however, want to disable compression for the rest of my site.
How can I get PHP to tell Apache not to gz-compress that particular output?

Comment: You can disable gzip for specific stuff in apache. You don't need to disable it for your entire site.

Answer (score 1):

Why not setting compression only for certain types of files, where compression make sense?

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript application/rss+xml
</IfModule>
```

Anything already compressed seems to be waste of time and cpu cycles.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but this doesn't work since the .php extension is mapped onto the MIME-type text/html as far as Apache is concerned, so the result is that output from PHP scripts is always compressed, including my dynamic .tar.gz archives, even though I set a different content-type from PHP.

Comment: Will disabling compression for certain php file only be sufficient for you? Try: SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(php)$" no-gzip dont-vary
You can also change request uri to describe your php file from which output should not be compressed.